# Codeless Application Insights Custom Counters

Tags: azure-application-insights

I'm running the codeless version of Application Insights in a Windows Server 2016 Azure VM. With the SDK I know it is possible to, for example, add custom telemetry so that I can update the cloudRoleName value that appears in my metrics.

My problem is that for the Performance Counters that are pushed by Application Insights it only provides a value like `w3wp#1` for process related data, but I really want to be able to relate this process to an application pool (ideally to a cloudRoleName)

Can I add any configuration to the App Insights agent that will allow me to add custom telemetry or will I have to add the SDK to each of the Dotnet Applications that are running on this VM to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to provide a custom value for cloudRoleName, right?

If that's the case, the only way is to use code(no way for codeless, see this [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/48326).) by using [ITelemetryInitializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#addmodify-properties-itelemetryinitializer), here is an example:

```
public class CloudRoleNameTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
      // set custom role name here
      telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleName = "Custom RoleName";
    }
}
```

For more details, you can refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-map#set-cloud-role-name).